# Automatically install Python on self hosted agents in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the FAQ of the [UsePython task doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version?view=azure-devops) it says that in order to use the UsePython task, you have to manually install the required version of Python under a specific folder structure in the Agent.ToolDirectory folder.

This is pretty daunting. Isn't there a way to configure Azure to a specific source (such as Artifactory instance or something like this) and tell it to install it from there?

Answer (score 1):

If you use self hosted agents on VM's you enter the area where tools for configuration managment could be handy. So you can use:

- powershell desired state configuration [install python](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/xPython/1.0.1) [quick tutorial](https://4sysops.com/archives/installing-software-with-powershell-dsc/)
- ansible
- chef

However, there is no simple way to acheive this. You can do it manually, or build a solution to handle software on your self hosted machines. You can also reuse repository for MS Hosted vm's and leverage this.